# Get data by ForeignKey

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, csla

I have `MainClass` and a `ChildData`.

I need to get `ChildData` given a `MainClass`.

The `MainClass` has a Property called `ChildClassProperty`. `ChildData` has got a ForeignKey to `MainClass`. How do I get the `ChildData` using LINQ?

so far:

```
using (var ctx = Csla.Data.ObjectContextManager<DB.Data.Entities>.GetManager(Model.EntitiesDatabase.Name))
{
    var xxx = from a in ctx.ObjectContext.ChildData where a...
}
```

Comment: You need to add the navigation for the relationship in the model. And use INCLUDE() in LINQ. This may http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/17/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-6-many-valued-associations.aspx help you

Comment: Find out if it is one-to-one, one-to-many or many-to-many relationship

Comment: Is the relationship between `MainClass` and `ChildClass` herarchical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ChildData` has a foreign key to `MainClass`. Do something like:

**Entities:**

```
public ChildData
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // primary key
    public int MainClassId { get; set; } // foreign key
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public MainClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // primary key
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

**Queries:**

```
public IQueryable<ChildData> GetChildData(int mainClassId)

using (var ctx = Csla.Data.ObjectContextManager<DB.Data.Entities>.GetManager(Model.EntitiesDatabase.Name))
{
    return ctx.ObjectContext.ChildData.Where(x => x.MainClassId == mainClassId);
}
```

or by passing in a full `MainClass` instance:

```
public IQueryable<ChildData> GetChildData(MainClass mainClass)

using (var ctx = Csla.Data.ObjectContextManager<DB.Data.Entities>.GetManager(Model.EntitiesDatabase.Name))
{
    return ctx.ObjectContext.ChildData.Where(x => x.MainClassId == mainClass.Id);
}
```